# Use CameraSource on com.google.android.gms.vision

Tags: java, xml

When I take a photo, the image returned to me is black, it only appears on Redmi Note 12

How can when I use this library will return me the desired image

As seen below is my picture after taking
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT1oQ.jpg)

Comment: Hi there, provide more details about your question, and also include some codes to reproduce

Comment: My codoe :             mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    mImgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });